# Verb "to be" without a subject not allowed?

Tags: grammar

I wrote the following sentence:

> The agent makes a choice and is rewarded.

A reviewer said this sentence is not correct, because the verb "to be" cannot be used without a subject. It should be:

> The agent makes a choice and it is rewarded.

Is only the second sentence correct or is the first one also okay?

Comment: The reviewer doesn't know what he's talking about. It's perfectly natural to "delete" repeated terms in contexts such as *He asked a question and [he] received an answer.*

Comment: I'm forced to wonder how that reviewer would define [compound predicate](http://www.k12reader.com/term/compound-predicate/).  I'm also forced to wonder how that reviewer understands Shakespeare's "to be or not to be", given that not even the slightest hint of a subject appears in *that* phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FumbleFingers said, the reviewer doesn't know what he's talking about.
The two sentences you gave mean two different things.

> The agent makes a choice and is rewarded.

In this case, the agent does two actions. He is the subject and there are two verb phrases 'makes a choice' and 'is rewarded'. This is the same kind of sentence structure as "The agent sings and dances", except here you have two verb phrases instead of one word verbs.

> The agent makes a choice and it is rewarded.

In this case, and is combining two subject verb phrases. "The agent makes a choice" and "it is rewarded". There is a different meaning here. In this sentence, the **choice** is the subject of the second half of the sentence, since we never use 'it' to refer to people.

If you wish to both please your reviewer and keep your original meaning, you might want to go with

> The agent makes a choice and he is rewarded.

But the 'he' here is completely optional.

Comment: The agent is not necessarily a person. It might be an animal or a computer program, which is why I used "it." But thank you and @FumbleFingers for your answers.